# Probability of drawing balls of unknown colours

Tags: probability

A bag with 5 balls of unknown colours is given and 2 balls are drawn, one by one from the bag and replaced . In both instances, the drawn ball was red. Again 2 balls are drawn from the bag. 
What is the probability that the balls are red? 
The balls being of unknown colours, are posing a problem.

Answer (score 0):

From what is given, we can safely assume that the number of red balls, say $x$, lies between $1$ and $5$ inclusive. Because there was replacement involved, it is possible that it was the same ball drawn twice, so we can't take away the possibility that there is only $1$ red ball, but we know there must be at least one.

Therefore we can find that the probability that two balls drawn with replacement are red **GIVEN** that in the previous experiment we have drawn two red balls with replacement lies between:
$$\left(\frac15\right)^2 \le P(\text{two red balls}) \le \left(\frac55\right)^2$$

This is as close as we can get with the information given. (In fact, since $x$ is limited to integers between $1$ and $5$ inclusive, we can show that there are only five different possibilities for the probability, but I'll leave that to the reader)

The fact that we were given the prior experiment is key; without knowing that, we would not be able to find anything about the probability besides the obvious that it lies between $0$ and $1$ like any other probability.